# What's most efficient way to remove obfuscated names (Minecraft)?

Tags: java, lua, minecraft

I've made a mod for Minecraft which allows Lua modding. Everything works fine, but normally the names of methods are obfuscated in MC. What's the best way to make the normal function names redirect to the obfuscated names?

For example the user makes a script for a block that prints hello world when right clicked:

`function onActivated(world, x, y, z, player)
   player:addChatMessage("hello world")
end`

addChatMessage should call the Java method EntityPlayer.func_71035_c(String text)

Comment: Try using `require'libname'` to get access to original library.  E.g., `(require'math').pi` to get nonobfuscated `math.pi`.

Comment: I'm talking about the Minecraft methods. Normally, all methods are obfuscated (func_number_a). So if I give a Player object as an argument I'll have to call player:func_34323_c(text) instead of player:addChatMessage(). The MC coder pack translates the method/field/class names to logical names (I have the files for the names).

Comment: Do you have access to translation algorithm (converting `func_34323_c` to `addChatMessage`)?  Is it a secret?

Comment: I have files containing the obfuscated names and the logical names (for fields, classes and methods). The real unobfuscated names are unkown, but the creators of MCP just give methods like func_34323_c a proper name.

Comment: Show example of such file please.

Comment: A part of the file: `func_70912_b,setTameSkin,2,
func_70913_u,getTameSkin,2,
func_70915_j,getShadingWhileShaking,2,Used when calculating the amount of shading to apply while the wolf is shaking.
func_70916_h,setAngry,2,Sets whether this wolf is angry or not.`

Comment: Found another file containing methods, classes and fields: `FD: yi/a net/minecraft/item/crafting/ShapelessRecipes/recipeOutput
MD: yi/a (Ltl;)Lwg; net/minecraft/item/crafting/ShapelessRecipes/getCraftingResult (Lnet/minecraft/inventory/InventoryCrafting;)Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;
MD: yi/a ()I net/minecraft/item/crafting/ShapelessRecipes/getRecipeSize ()I
MD: yi/b ()Lwg; net/minecraft/item/crafting/ShapelessRecipes/getRecipeOutput ()Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- translation file (translation.txt)
func_70912_b,setTameSkin,2,
func_70913_u,getTameSkin,2,
func_70915_j,getShadingWhileShaking,2,Used when calculating the amount of shading to apply while the wolf is shaking.
func_70916_h,setAngry,2,Sets whether this wolf is angry.


-- obfuscated program (script.lua)
x:func_70913_u(y, z)
x:func_70915_j(y, z)


-- your preprocessor (preprocessor.lua)
local transl = {}
for line in io.lines'translation.txt' do
   local obf, orig = line:match'^(.-),(.-),'
   transl[obf] = orig
end
local script = assert(io.open('script.lua','rb')):read'*a'
local output = assert(io.open('script2.lua','wb'))
output:write((script:gsub('[%w_]+',transl)))
output:close()


-- preprocessor output (script2.lua)
x:getTameSkin(y, z)
x:getShadingWhileShaking(y, z)
```

---

**EDIT :**

```
local obfuscations = {}
for line in io.lines'translation.txt' do
   local obf, orig = line:match'^(.-),(.-),'
   obfuscations[orig] = obf
end

local function get_obf_key_value(t, k, __index)
   local value = __index and __index(t, k)
   if value == nil and obfuscations[k] then
      value = t[obfuscations[k]]
   end
   return value
end

local cache = {get_obf_key_value = true}

local function __index_constructor(__index)
   if not __index then
      return get_obf_key_value
   end
   local old__index = cache[__index]
   if old__index then
      return old__index == true and __index or old__index
   else
      local function new__index(t, k)
         return get_obf_key_value(t, k, __index)
      end
      cache[__index] = new__index
      cache[new__index] = true
      return new__index
   end
end

local obf_mt = {__index = get_obf_key_value}

local function correct_metatable(object)
   local mt = getmetatable(object)
   if mt == nil then
      setmetatable(object, obf_mt)
   else
      local __index = mt.__index
      if __index == nil or type(__index) == 'function' then
          mt.__index = __index_constructor(__index)
      else
         correct_metatable(__index)
      end
   end
end

-- you should call correct_metatable(class_or_object_of_that_class)
-- at least once for every class
correct_metatable(wolf)
correct_metatable(goat)
correct_metatable(cabbage)
...
```

Comment: Normally MC is obfuscated so I need to make the logical function names obfuscated so the user doesn't have to know the obfuscated name. The problem is that I can't obfuscate Lua files every tick (20 times a second). I need to somehow redirect the function to the obfuscated function.

Comment: @Hackingroelz - It would require to change large amount of metatables (for every class used).

Comment: So, I'll have to change the metatable of every object I give to a function? And would this really cause a lot of lag? I could add a global function for calling Java methods, but it'd be better without of course.

Comment: @Hackingroelz - See my appended answer.  This is a way to correct metatables for classes.